# Cannot find class for bean with name defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm posting my query after visiting numerous question posted before on same context, unfortunately none of them resolved my problem. I'm trying a complete xml based configuration in spring without using any annotation. But as soon as i launch the application, i'm getting the following exception.

> Cannot find class [com.kashyap.springboot.xml.JdbcConnectionXML.java]
>   for bean with name 'connection' defined in class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.kashyap.springboot.xml.JdbcConnectionXML.java

Things i've already taken care of :-

1. Namespace for component scan re-examined.
2. Tag for component scan entered.
3. Bean tag with proper classes' qualified name re-examined.
4. Bean property and references re-visited.
5. applicationContext.xml is located on path src/main/resources so no
   absolute path required.
6. Context initialized with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class.

Classes are already defined with default public constructors for instantiation required by reflection.(though it is not mandatory, used it as precaution). Alas!!! none of the these things worked. Please find the classes and xml below.

```
package com.kashyap.springboot.xml;
public class JdbcConnectionXML {
    public JdbcConnectionXML(){
        System.out.println("JDBC XML Constructor Called");
    }
}

package com.kashyap.springboot.xml;
public class PrototypeXMLDAO {
    public PrototypeXMLDAO(){
        System.out.println("PrototypeXMLDAO Constructor Called");
    }   
    private JdbcConnectionXML connection;
    public JdbcConnectionXML getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
    public void setConnection(JdbcConnectionXML connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
}


package com.kashyap.springboot.xml;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class SpringbootdevApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");) {
            PrototypeXMLDAO pdCDIOne = context.getBean(PrototypeXMLDAO.class);
            PrototypeXMLDAO pdCDITwo = context.getBean(PrototypeXMLDAO.class);
            System.out.println(pdCDIOne);
            System.out.println(pdCDIOne.getConnection());
            System.out.println(pdCDITwo);
            System.out.println(pdCDITwo.getConnection());
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kashyap.springboot.xml" />

    <bean id="connection" class="com.kashyap.springboot.xml.JdbcConnectionXML">
    </bean>
    <bean id="prototype" class="com.kashyap.springboot.xml.PrototypeXMLDAO">
        <property name="connection" ref="connection"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The stack-trace on console as follows:-

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [com.kashyap.springboot.xml.JdbcConnectionXML.java] for
>   bean with name 'connection' defined in class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.kashyap.springboot.xml.JdbcConnectionXML.java     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:670)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1007)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:739)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
>     at
>   com.kashyap.springboot.xml.SpringbootdevApplication.main(SpringbootdevApplication.java:13)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.kashyap.springboot.xml.JdbcConnectionXML.java     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255)  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:418)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372)
>     ... 10 more

If required i'll post the pom.xml too. Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This `Cannot find class [com.kashyap.springboot.xml.JdbcConnectionXML.java]` is suspicious. You have `.java` suffix here but not in the `applicationContext.xml`. Somehow I have a feeling you've posted something different than your actual code. Make sure you did not write `.java` suffix in your `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: Could be that the application has not been built, that is no classes in target directory.

Comment: @lexicore thanks for responding but the code posted is exactly the same in IDE.

Comment: @ArthurNoseda thanks for making me think in that direction. Though i've checked marked auto build. I just forced updated using maven. Eureka!!! it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: build again please.

Comment: Adding to @ArthurNoseda  comment, in my case the classes were generated in the classes directory but due to some reason same classes were not being packaged in the war file which was the cause of this exception.